# How do I activate database settings from my settings.py DATABASES array based on environment?

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, settings

I'm using Django with Python 3.7.  I have a settings.py file, which includes some database settings ...

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mainpage',
        'USER': 'mainpage',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    },
    'production': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mainpage',
        'USER': 'mainpage',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

The file includes a bunch of other things but I have only included the database array here.  Is it possible to activate a particular database configuration from my array based on my environment or an environment variable?  I would prefer not to have multiple settings files because then I have to repeat a lot of other configurations in them that do not change across environment.  I'm happy to move the database settings to their own files if that's what it takes but I'm not sure how they would be activated.

**Edit:** Per Scott Skiles' answer, this is the error I'm getting when I remove settings.py and add the other directory and files, but I get this error when loading my Python console ...

```
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/mainpage_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Here is my **init**.py file.  I haven't altered it since the project was created ...

```
"""
Settings and configuration for Django.

Read values from the module specified by the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment
variable, and then from django.conf.global_settings; see the global_settings.py
for a list of all possible variables.
"""

import importlib
import os
import time
import warnings
from pathlib import Path

from django.conf import global_settings
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango30Warning
from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty

ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"


class LazySettings(LazyObject):
    """
    A lazy proxy for either global Django settings or a custom settings object.
    The user can manually configure settings prior to using them. Otherwise,
    Django uses the settings module pointed to by DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
    """
    def _setup(self, name=None):
        """
        Load the settings module pointed to by the environment variable. This
        is used the first time settings are needed, if the user hasn't
        configured settings manually.
        """
        settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
        if not settings_module:
            desc = ("setting %s" % name) if name else "settings"
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "Requested %s, but settings are not configured. "
                "You must either define the environment variable %s "
                "or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."
                % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

    def __repr__(self):
        # Hardcode the class name as otherwise it yields 'Settings'.
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            return '<LazySettings [Unevaluated]>'
        return '<LazySettings "%(settings_module)s">' % {
            'settings_module': self._wrapped.SETTINGS_MODULE,
        }

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Return the value of a setting and cache it in self.__dict__."""
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            self._setup(name)
        val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
        self.__dict__[name] = val
        return val

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        """
        Set the value of setting. Clear all cached values if _wrapped changes
        (@override_settings does this) or clear single values when set.
        """
        if name == '_wrapped':
            self.__dict__.clear()
        else:
            self.__dict__.pop(name, None)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        """Delete a setting and clear it from cache if needed."""
        super().__delattr__(name)
        self.__dict__.pop(name, None)

    def configure(self, default_settings=global_settings, **options):
        """
        Called to manually configure the settings. The 'default_settings'
        parameter sets where to retrieve any unspecified values from (its
        argument must support attribute access (__getattr__)).
        """
        if self._wrapped is not empty:
            raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')
        holder = UserSettingsHolder(default_settings)
        for name, value in options.items():
            setattr(holder, name, value)
        self._wrapped = holder

    @property
    def configured(self):
        """Return True if the settings have already been configured."""
        return self._wrapped is not empty


class Settings:
    def __init__(self, settings_module):
        # update this dict from global settings (but only for ALL_CAPS settings)
        for setting in dir(global_settings):
            if setting.isupper():
                setattr(self, setting, getattr(global_settings, setting))

        # store the settings module in case someone later cares
        self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module

        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)

        tuple_settings = (
            "INSTALLED_APPS",
            "TEMPLATE_DIRS",
            "LOCALE_PATHS",
        )
        self._explicit_settings = set()
        for setting in dir(mod):
            if setting.isupper():
                setting_value = getattr(mod, setting)

                if (setting in tuple_settings and
                        not isinstance(setting_value, (list, tuple))):
                    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The %s setting must be a list or a tuple. " % setting)
                setattr(self, setting, setting_value)
                self._explicit_settings.add(setting)

        if not self.SECRET_KEY:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")

        if self.is_overridden('DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE'):
            warnings.warn('The DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE setting is deprecated.', RemovedInDjango30Warning)

        if hasattr(time, 'tzset') and self.TIME_ZONE:
            # When we can, attempt to validate the timezone. If we can't find
            # this file, no check happens and it's harmless.
            zoneinfo_root = Path('/usr/share/zoneinfo')
            zone_info_file = zoneinfo_root.joinpath(*self.TIME_ZONE.split('/'))
            if zoneinfo_root.exists() and not zone_info_file.exists():
                raise ValueError("Incorrect timezone setting: %s" % self.TIME_ZONE)
            # Move the time zone info into os.environ. See ticket #2315 for why
            # we don't do this unconditionally (breaks Windows).
            os.environ['TZ'] = self.TIME_ZONE
            time.tzset()

    def is_overridden(self, setting):
        return setting in self._explicit_settings

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%(cls)s "%(settings_module)s">' % {
            'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
            'settings_module': self.SETTINGS_MODULE,
        }


class UserSettingsHolder:
    """Holder for user configured settings."""
    # SETTINGS_MODULE doesn't make much sense in the manually configured
    # (standalone) case.
    SETTINGS_MODULE = None

    def __init__(self, default_settings):
        """
        Requests for configuration variables not in this class are satisfied
        from the module specified in default_settings (if possible).
        """
        self.__dict__['_deleted'] = set()
        self.default_settings = default_settings

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._deleted:
            raise AttributeError
        return getattr(self.default_settings, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._deleted.discard(name)
        if name == 'DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE':
            warnings.warn('The DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE setting is deprecated.', RemovedInDjango30Warning)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        self._deleted.add(name)
        if hasattr(self, name):
            super().__delattr__(name)

    def __dir__(self):
        return sorted(
            s for s in list(self.__dict__) + dir(self.default_settings)
            if s not in self._deleted
        )

    def is_overridden(self, setting):
        deleted = (setting in self._deleted)
        set_locally = (setting in self.__dict__)
        set_on_default = getattr(self.default_settings, 'is_overridden', lambda s: False)(setting)
        return deleted or set_locally or set_on_default

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<%(cls)s>' % {
            'cls': self.__class__.__name__,
        }


settings = LazySettings()
```

Comment: In the different environments I have different db connections, so I'd like to have a good way to separate the db connection info per environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is following the approach where you use a separate 'settings' directory. Be careful switching to this as it might break some things initially, such as your manage.py file.

Both `dev.py` and `prod.py` would import stuff from `base.py`. Anything that is common to both dev and prod goes into base. Anything that is unique to development goes into `dev.py` and anything that is specific to production goes into `prod.py`.

### .bashrc:

```
export DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT=true
```

### manage.py

```
import os

if os.environ['DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT'] == 'true':
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings.dev")
else:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings.prod")
```

### directory structure

```
-> app
--> settings
---> base.py
---> prod.py
---> dev.py
```

### dev.py

```
from app.settings.base import * 

# This will overwrite anything in base.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mainpage',
        'USER': 'mainpage',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    },
}
```

## Modify any locations that use `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to use the new env var, such as `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

if os.environ["DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT"]:
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mainpage.settings.dev")
else: 
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mainpage.settings.prod")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

~

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  So would my current settings.py file become base.py, minus the DATABASES stuff?

Comment: Both `dev.py` and `prod.py` would import stuff from `base.py`. Anything that is common to both dev and prod goes into base. Anything that is unique to development goes into `dev.py` and anything that is specific to production goes into `prod.py`.

Comment: I moved settings.py to the "base.py" location you suggested and created the other files, but I get an error loading my console (shown in my edit).  Isn't a default Python project looking for settings.py somewhere so do I need to tell it that "settings.py" no longer exists and look for something else?

Comment: @Dave - See update. Anywhere that `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set will need to be changed.

Comment: Cool, per you suggestion found that block of code in the wsgi.py file.  Then I looked at your answer and you had also edited it to include that, so i was confident I was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I just use an environment variable and the package [environ](https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/).

```
env = environ.Env()
if not env.bool('PRODUCTION', 'False'):
    # Select this PRODUCTTION=False or if not defined 
    DATABASES = 'default': {
        # ...
    }
else:
   DATABASES = 'default': {
       # ...
    }
```

Comment: Where is this code located?  Also is "PRODUTION" an environment variable set in ~/.profile or some kind of file like that?

Comment: This is a good solution too. You can use `os.enviorn['ENV_VAR_NAME']` to determine if it is in testing. So it would be, if `os.environ['DJANGO_DEVELOPMENT']` then dev DB

Comment: @Dave where you define the environment variable depends on yuor build/deployment system.